# Mechanical solution for engaging and disengaging an idler gear to output gear

Tags: gears, mechanisms, springs

[image]I am building a conveyor lift to send cut plywood (4ft x 8ft x 40mm) into a 20-tier conveyor rack. I would like my conveyor motor to be on the conveyor lift only. I need the conveyor motor to drive the lift conveyor belt and the rack conveyor belt when it stops on that level. Please point me to the right mechanism or gear to use. I prefer fully mechanical than adding more electric pushers.

Answer (score 1):

A chain drive to sprockets, one for each that you show. Only one chain with idlers to make sure sufficient teeth are engaged.

Then a magnetic clutch to engage the level needed.

Comment: I think it will still be simpler for the sprocket / gears to engage directly. I like the motor to be driving the idler to link the output gear and subsequently power the output while maintaining the link.